# calculate a 2d array in python using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a 2d array in python using numpy.
In the following, I just create the 2d array with numbers 1,2,3,...
I should calculate an expression to produce each element of it.
Thank you

```
import numpy as np
my_2darray = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

Comment: `np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3)`?

Comment: I want to calculate a formula for each entry. How can I put them in the array?

Comment: What do you mean a formula? What's the formula you want to apply?

Comment: anything, no different!

Answer (score 0):

you can create a 2d array of size 2 x 3 using numpy in that way:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32)
```

Comment: I want to calculate a formula for each entry. How can I put them in the array?

Comment: what do you mean by a formula ?